# Mining Gutenberg project, can't creat access to subdirectories

Tags: python, html, text-mining

I'm a trying to create a loop for accessing Gutenberg Project Mirror Archive with a Python script. The problem I'm having is that I can create the propoer loop since, the subdirectories change. For example:
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/1/11/11.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/22/23.txt

And so on. I'm using this script, but it will start shifting the numbers, giving this as a result where the subdirectory doesn't match anymore with the file :

```
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/23/23.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/24/24.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/25/25.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/26/26.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/27/27.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/2/28/28.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/3/29/29.txt
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/3/30/30.txt
```

I'm using this sort of basic loop:

```
liston = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5,6,7,8,9,]
pos = 10
luve= [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
les = 0
for y in luve:

    les = les +1


    for x in liston:
        pos = pos + 1


        print "http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/"+str(les)+"/"+str(pos)+"/"+str(pos)+".txt"
```

thank you very much.

Comment: You might try looking into a tool like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org)

Answer (score 0):

```
template = "http://mirror.its.dal.ca/gutenberg/{root}/{index}/{index}.txt"
for root in range(1, 10):
    for c_index in range(0, 10):
        print template.format(root=root, index=(root*10+c_index))
```